# what is the iOS equivalent of mixpanel.get_property() in javascript

Tags: ios, mixpanel

I am trying to increment a super property in mixpanel iOS (OBJC). I am following this blog to do so:
https://blog.mixpanel.com/2015/01/29/incremental-super-properties/

As you can see, it does what I want in javascript using get_property method of mixpanel. But I need to do the same thing on iOS. I can't seem to figure out what is the equivalent of `mixpanel.get_property()` on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-iphone/Classes/Mixpanel/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/Mixpanel/currentSuperProperties

The above link is equivalent to
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.get_property

Both functions return super properties

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.